# open application with key pressing

Tags: java, eclipse, swing, jframe

I am building this pop up learning new languages application which if user found an unknown word he can simply press any keyboard key (like e.g alt+p) so that the app pops up and allow him to insert the new word

and in order to make the key get listened to from anywhere i coded the following

```
public class IsKeyPressed extends JFrame implements KeyListener {
public IsKeyPressed() {
    this.setExtendedState(MAXIMIZED_BOTH);
    this.setUndecorated(true);
    this.setBackground(new Color(0, 0, 0, 0));
    this.addKeyListener(this);
    this.setAlwaysOnTop(true);
    this.setVisible(true);
    while (true) {
        this.toFront();
        this.requestFocus();
        this.repaint();
    }
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    new IsKeyPressed();
}

@Override
public void keyPressed(KeyEvent ke) {

    //open the pop up application
}
```

but it does only work fine if the frame is focused from taskbar 
so basically it ّdoesn`t work

any idea how to fix ? thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> but it does only work fine if the frame is focused from taskbar so basically it ّdoesn`t work
>
> any idea how to fix ?

Not with core Java, that's for sure. You're asking how to create a general key listener, one that works even if the application doesn't have focus, and this is something core Java GUI libraries can't do on there own, for the very reason that this functionality would require the coder to get close to the OS to make OS-specific calls, and Java was built to be as OS-agnostic as possible.

So possible solutions include

- writing your own OS routines in C and meshing them with your Java program using JNI
- writing Java OS routines using JNA
- Or (my favorite) use an OS specific tool, such as Auto-It for Windows, to capture the key press and revive your program, and then meshing this with your program via streams.

Comment: isn`t there anyway around it?..
like grapping focus for the frame everytime it lose it ?..
because i couldnt found anything that can grap the focus for the frame

Comment: @KareemElsayed: that would be a terrible solution if it were possible, but thankfully, it's not possible.

Comment: so tools wont be helpful for  spreading my application ,the only way is using C i think...can you give me any thing i can search for as i know nothing in C

Comment: @KareemElsayed: I take exception to your statement about tools as a small autoit program can easily be packaged with your program if need be. As for your search request, it's a bit broad. I would use the first suggestion above last, and would prefer 1) tools/library 2) JNA and last 3) JNI in that order.